# After XC 9.0.2 install, Store home page shows Default Sitecore CMS page

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

After the successful install of the Sitecore XC 9.0.2. I get the store homepage same as the Sitecore CMS. 
Not sure if this has to do with port binding. 
I will really appreciate if some expert can help me out with this issue.
Screenshots of the issue are attached below.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is everything published?

Comment: Yes everything is published. Tried to republished and smart publish again

Comment: @RatneshJ, I'm facing the same issue. may I know how did you fix this?

Answer (score 2):

That’s because you did not use the default host name `sxa.storefront.com`.
 To correct that:

log into `sc9.sc/sitecore/`

access `/sitecore/content/Sitecore/Storefront/Settings/Site Grouping/Storefront`

update Host Name to `storefront.local`

then publish

This should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Site Grouping` setting looks valid (has properly configured `Host Name`). Please double check that whole site is published.

Such behavior may also happen if your license doesn't support SXA.